# Sending alert by analyzing Azure logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-alerts

I'm using an azure function which writes a log:

```
def main(name: str) :

connect_str = os.getenv('AzureWebJobsStorage')
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_str, container_name="testcsv", 
blob_name=name)
exists = blob.exists()

if (exists == False):
    logging.info(f"The blob exists \n")

else:
    logging.error(f"The blob does not exist \n")
    

return exists
```

I want to send an alert when I find 'The blob does not exist' in my log. I think I have to use custom log search in alerts. Do you know how ?

Comment: Try https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/alerts-based-on-analytics-query-using-custom-log-search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alert is always triggered by a telemetry query. We can set up an alert on bad behaviours if we can formulate a query that reveals them.

As of now, we could create Custom Alerts i.e., based on `Number of results` and `Metric Measurement`.

Refer to the [Microsoft Blog on Alert based on Analytics query using Custom Log Search](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/alerts-based-on-analytics-query-using-custom-log-search/) for more information.